# React re-render issue after clicking link to open new tab on Android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs

Am creating an app that opens a link in a new tab, when viewing this on an Android phone there's an odd content flash. I cannot replicate on desktop, and have console logged out the rendering and state changes and debugged through Android Studio but cannot figure out where the problem lies.

Is there something going on with the Android Chrome browser rendering causing this?

Any suggestions welcome :)

[[image: Attached is a video of it showing the title in the panel changing on click]]

Tried and proven this issue on:

- Google Pixel Android phone
- Android Studio running an Android emulator locally
- tried playing with Network/CPU throttling on desktop without any of the same effects
- Created this as a code sandbox using React CRA and seeing the issue

Here's the sample code: https://jsfiddle.net/51enrfuh/1/

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const modals = {
  apple: {
    id: 'apple',
    title: 'Apple',
    url: 'https://apple.com',
  },

  orange: {
    id: 'orange',
    title: 'Orange',
    url: 'https://www.orange.com/',
  },
};

function App() {
  const [currentlyActiveModal, setCurrentlyActiveModal] = useState('');
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setCurrentlyActiveModal('apple')}>
        Go to Apple
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setCurrentlyActiveModal('orange')}>
        Go to Orange
      </button>

      {currentlyActiveModal !== '' && (
        <div style={{ background: 'lightgrey', padding: '1rem', margin: '1rem' }}>
          <h1 style={{ color: modals[currentlyActiveModal].title === 'Orange' ? 'green' : 'red' }}>
            {modals[currentlyActiveModal].title}
          </h1>
          <a href={modals[currentlyActiveModal].url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
            {modals[currentlyActiveModal].title} link
          </a>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```